# Move a Bunch of Columns into 2 Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large dataset currently organized, essentially, in many pairs of columns. I'm trying to stack them all into just 2 columns. Thus, in Column A, I want to stack the data from Column A, C, E, etc.; in Column B, the data from Column B, D, F, etc. Anybody know some VBA code or any other tips that will make this a quick fix? Thanks!

Comment: How many columns?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-text-from-two-or-more-cells-into-one-cell-81ba0946-ce78-42ed-b3c3-21340eb164a6 .... and .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjGGZIEN9E0

Comment: @ExcelHero Yes, you are right. I got it wrong. I thought OP wants to merger it in once cell with line breaks (using CHAR(10))  .. Yes. you are right. If OP wants it stacked in different cells it could be done better with a macro. Thanks for the macros. Great learning.

Comment: @ExcelHero or may be .. Please see ..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3mCejcOAfU

Comment: Oz is a great guy and he is also an alumni of my course, but that video does not answer this question either... and it's a lot of manual work to set it up. My answer specifically solves the OP's problem and it runs in about 5 milliseconds.

Comment: You can usually do that quick and easy using Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in a standard code module...

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim a&, b&, i&, m&, j&, v, z

    With [a1].CurrentRegion
        v = .Value2
        z = [a:b]
        a = [counta(a:a)]
        b = [counta(b:b)]

        For j = 3 To UBound(v, 2)
            Select Case j Mod 2
                Case 1
                    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
                        If Len(v(i, j)) = 0 Then Exit For
                        a = a + 1
                        z(a, 1) = v(i, j)
                    Next
                Case 0
                     For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
                        If Len(v(i, j)) = 0 Then Exit For
                        b = b + 1
                        z(b, 2) = v(i, j)
                    Next
            End Select
        Next

        .ClearContents
        m = a: If b > m Then m = b
        [a1:b1].Resize(m) = z
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Update

Here's a refactored version...

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim a&, b&, m&, j&, v, z

    With [a1].CurrentRegion
        z = [a:b]
        v = .Value2
        a = [counta(a:a)]
        b = [counta(b:b)]

        For j = 3 To UBound(v, 2)
            Select Case j Mod 2
                Case 1: ProcessColumn a, 1, j, v, z
                Case 0: ProcessColumn b, 2, j, v, z
            End Select
        Next

        .ClearContents
        m = a: If b > m Then m = b
        [a1:b1].Resize(m) = z
    End With
End Sub

Sub ProcessColumn(ndx&, d&, j&, v, z)
    Dim i&

    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Len(v(i, j)) = 0 Then Exit For
        ndx = ndx + 1
        z(ndx, d) = v(i, j)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are indeed a hero. My apologies for not thanking you sooner (it took a while for me to get back to this process given the state of the world right now), but yes, this works absolutely flawlessly and very quickly. Exceedingly grateful.